# jQuery hide not working inside .post success function

Tags: jquery, html, post, hide

Can anyone tell me why my code: `$(this).parent().hide();` works (the selected div is hidden) when placed outside of my `.post()` like:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.reply-message-form', function(e) {

        $(this).parent().hide();

        if($(this).children('.post-reply-message-textarea').val() == '')
            return false;

        $.post("<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('event/view', array('id'=>Yii::app()->controller->actionParams['id'])); ?>", 
        $(this).serialize(), function(response) {

            var responseObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            // if successful.. process..
            if (responseObject.success == true) {

            } else {
                alert('failed');
            }

        });
        return false;
    }) ;
```

however if the `.hide()` is put *inside* the `.post()` success function nothing happens..?! Code when inside:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.reply-message-form', function(e) {

        if($(this).children('.post-reply-message-textarea').val() == '')
            return false;

        $.post("<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('event/view', array('id'=>Yii::app()->controller->actionParams['id'])); ?>", 
        $(this).serialize(), function(response) {

            $(this).parent().hide();
            return false;
            var responseObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
            // if successful.. process..
            if (responseObject.success == true) {

            } else {
                alert('failed');
            }

        });
        return false;
    }) ;
```

just to clear any doubts - the responseObject.success does == true (I have confirmed that with alerts etc).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

try, because $(this) isnt the same when you move in the post callback.

```
$(document).on('submit', '.reply-message-form', function(e) {
    var elt = $(this).parent();
    if($(this).children('.post-reply-message-textarea').val() == '')
        return false;

    $.post("<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('event/view', array('id'=>Yii::app()->controller->actionParams['id'])); ?>", 
    $(this).serialize(), function(response) {

        $(elt).hide();
        return false;
        var responseObject = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
        // if successful.. process..
        if (responseObject.success == true) {

        } else {
            alert('failed');
        }

    });
    return false;
}) ;
```

Comment: You beat me.  I like this way, since all you need is the parent in the success callback.

Answer (score 1):

`this` doesn't represent the submitted form anymore, since it is in the callback from the ajax call.  Before you make the ajax call, set a variable with this.

```
var myForm = this;
```

Then in your success callback, reference `$(myForm)`